# Display error html for offline mode in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

I have an app that could go in to offline mode. For that i have implemented a HostListener which listens to apps events.

```
@HostListener('window:offline', ['$event']) onOffline() {
   this.isOnline = false;
}
```

This works fine and I display an error message:

```
<div *ngIf="!isOnline"> 
  <div class="network-div">
    <mat-icon class="network-icon">cloud_off</mat-icon>
  </div>
  <p class="network-text">Network error - unable to connect. 
    Please try again or contact support if error persists, contact the NCR 
    support desk.</p>
</div>
```

When i go offline, i get the desired message, but now that internet is down, when i refresh, I get the usual google error message with that dinasour.

I can't render the error HTML in my angular component anymore since its running in offline mode. I need to render the above HTML when i refresh.

When i click on 'Offline' of developer tool, i render an HTML and below is the screenshot:
[image]

When i refresh the same page (still in offline mode),i receive the following:
[image]

How should i handle this?

Comment: Do you have a service worker ?

Comment: Yes. But i am having a hard time configuring the manifest file. It caches basic js and css. How do i cache a component?

Comment: component **is** basic JS. When you build your application, it translates all of your HTML and TS code to full JS components.

Answer (score 0):

if you are registering service worker you can try:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!navigator.onLine) {
      this.isOnline = false;
    }
  }
```

note that you should check it after build your project and serve it.

Comment: mine application is in Angular 5. In that case how can I redirect offline page (I've custom page like 404 error)

Answer (score 0):

About the browser's cache visit: [How to Enable Offline Browsing in Firefox](https://www.howtogeek.com/263854/how-to-enable-offline-browsing-in-firefox/)
If you attach the event listener to document.body on a browser, Chrome couldn't work.
You can register listeners for these events:

1. using addEventListener on the window, document, or document.body
2. by setting .onoffline properties on document or document.body to a
           JavaScript Function object.
3. by specifying onoffline="..."
           attributes on the  tag in the HTML markup.

**A javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var log = document.getElementById("log");

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    status.className = condition;
    status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();

    log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Event: " + event.type + "; Status: " + condition);
  }

  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the networks tab in your developer tools and see if the SW is registered and offline works by running Audit.
[image]